# How do I create a file explorer like structure with children dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to create a file explorer in ReactJS and am stuck at one point as to how to create elements from the array such that each **object** in the array should act as a parent to the **strings** present in the object index as an array. I need to do this dynamically only using the following array

```
const initialItems = [
  "index.js",
  {
    src: ["styles.css", "index.css"]
  },
  "App.js",
  {
    public: [
      "favicon.jpg",
      {
        images: ["logo.jpg", "header.png"]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

The above should look something like this:

```
<div>index.js</div>
<div>App.js</div>
<div>
  src
  <div>styles.css</div>
  <div>index.css</div>
</div>
```

I tried recursively passing the parent to each recursive call but got an error when appending the children to the parent.
I realized later that this should be done using stacks to maintain the order, but I am stuck on how to get the children to append the parent.

The code for that looked something like this:

```
items.forEach((item) => {
    if (typeof item === "object" && !Array.isArray(item)) {
      const key = Object.keys(item)[0];
      const newArr = item[key];

      result = [
        ...result,
        ...getRenderedItems(newArr, getDivElement(String(key), true))
      ];
    } else {
      const childElement = getDivElement(item);
      if(!parent) {
        result.push(childElement)
      }
      else {
        parent.appendChild(childElement) // error here, how can I achieve this?
      }
    }
  });
```

Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a recursive component that calls itself. It seems like you'd like "leaf" items first, so sort the list:

```js
const sortItems = (a, b) => {
  const aType = typeof a;
  const bType = typeof b;
  if (aType === bType) return 0;
  return aType === 'string' ? -1 : 1;
};

items.sort(sortItems)
```

Each item seems to have a `<div>` wrapper. If the item is a string, it is used as-is, otherwise, if it is an object, use the first key:

```
<List items={initialItems} />

function List({ items }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {items
        .sort(sortItems)
         .map((item) => (
           <div key={i}>
             {typeof item === 'string' ? item : Object.keys(item)[0]}
           </div>
         ))
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

After the "main" item text, if it is an object, the items are taken from the first key's value:

```
<div key={i}>
  …
  {typeof item !== 'string' && <List items={Object.values(item)[0]} />}
</div>
```

Full example:

```js
const initialItems = [
  "index.js",
  {
    src: ["styles.css", "index.css"]
  },
  "App.js",
  {
    public: [
      "favicon.jpg",
      {
        images: ["logo.jpg", "header.png"]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const sortItems = (a, b) => {
  const aType = typeof a;
  const bType = typeof b;
  if (aType === bType) return 0;
  return aType === 'string' ? -1 : 1;
};

function List({ items }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {items
        .sort(sortItems)
        .map((item, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            {typeof item === 'string' ? item : Object.keys(item)[0]}
            {typeof item !== 'string' && <List items={Object.values(item)[0]} />}
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<List items={initialItems} />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```